# symfony 1.4: How to pass exception message to error.html.php?

Tags: exception, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I tried using special variable `$message` described here http://www.symfony-project.org/cookbook/1_2/en/error_templates but it seems this variable isn't defined in symfony 1.4, at least it doesn't contain message passed to exception this way `throw new sfException('some message')`

Do you know other way to pass this message to error.html.php ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll need to do some custom error handling. We implemented a forward to a custom symfony action ourselves. Be cautious though, this action itself could be triggering an exception too, you need to take that into account.

The following might be a good start. First add a listener for the event, a good place would be ProjectConfiguration.class.php:

```
$this->dispatcher->connect('application.throw_exception', array('MyClass', 'handleException'));
```

Using the event handler might suffice for what you want to do with the exception, for example if you just want to mail a stack trace to the admin. We wanted to forward to a custom action to display and process a feedback form. Our event handler looked something like this:

```
class MyClass {
  public static function handleException(sfEvent $event) {
    $moduleName = sfConfig::get('sf_error_500_module', 'error');
    $actionName = sfConfig::get('sf_error_500_action', 'error500');
    sfContext::getInstance()->getRequest()->addRequestParameters(array('exception' => $event->getSubject()));
    $event->setReturnValue(true);
    sfContext::getInstance()->getController()->forward($moduleName, $actionName);
  }
}
```

You can now configure the module and action to forward to on an exception in settings.yml

```
all:
  .actions:
    error_500_module:       error
    error_500_action:       error500
```

In the action itself you can now do whatever you want with the exception, eg. display the feedback form to contact the administrator. You can get the exception itself by using $request->getParameter('exception')

Comment: +1 Thank you very much! Our system supports theming and without this we wouldn't have been able to support theming of error 500 pages too. Much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Does connecting your custom function to `application.throw_exception` *overwrite* symfony's default behavior on that event? If yes, can I prevent it with calling `self::parent()` inside the custom function? I just would like to *add* some functionality..

Comment: @Tapper you should be able to accomplish that by modifying the return value, try $event->setReturnValue(false) instead

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a much simpler answer. On Symfony 1.4 `$message` is indeed not defined, but `$exception` is (it contains the exception object).

So just echo `$exception->message`.

Et voilà!

Answer (score 0):

I've found another trick to do that - `sfContext` can be used to pass exception message to `error.html.php` but custom function have to be used to throw exception. For example:

```
class myToolkit {
  public static function throwException($message) 
    {
      sfContext::getInstance()->set('error_msg', $message);
      throw new sfException($message);
    }
```

than insted of using `throw new sfException('some message')` you should use `myToolkit::throwException('some message')`

To display message in `error.html.php` use `<?php echo sfContext::getInstance()->get('error_msg') ?>`