# Customizing All errors symfony 1.4

Tags: symfony1, custom-errors

Sorry for my English and writing through a translator.

I'm new here and I'm a bit lost in what I want, maybe you can help me out if they wish, as explained here:

I want to customize all the errors that may be produced (any status code that is a mistake. 404, 500, 204, 301 .... etc.) And also show suggestions based on the "module" and/or "action" from where the error occurred.

I also wish I could tell by the file redirection "setting.yml" application, something like this:

```
error_404_module: common
error_404_action: errors
error_500_module: common
error_500_action: errors
error_204_module: common
error_204_action: errors
error_301_module: common
error_301_action: errors
........
```

Within the "app/frontend/modules/common" in the "action.class.php" define "executeErrors" in which I receive the status code that has occurred and the module where the error occurred or except for well, getting partial show "app/frontend/modules/common/templates/_errorXXXSuccess.php" and the partial of the suggestion that I seek and extract the module "referer" where the error occurred.

Well, that's the idea, dynamic content for different types of error in different circumstances and working perfectly with the type codes 404 but not with the rest ...

I read that could place me in the middle of the event by creating a file "config/error.html.php" and "config/exception.html.php". Indeed if I produce such a 500 error and manually these files are executed. The problem is that from there I can not access variables from symfony. Because if so I could invoke "common/errors" and bad send as parameters the error status code and the module where it occurred, but it is not. From there all I can do is play with $ _SERVER and routing.yml but can not get good results because the environment is mixed with Development Production (/frontend_dev.php) and is something I also want to avoid.

That is, I want to get as in "setting.yml" does "error_404_module" and "error_404_action" but with different error codes. Thus allowing me to show my custom pages in production based on "error or exception" and/or "module or action" where the error has been released from production, and in case of being in development mode (/frontend_dev.php/....), show the symfony Dispatch.

Surely life is complicandome and has a simpler way to do what I want but after thousands of combinations do not get the right result. Even if symfony may not allow other types of error redirect from "setting.yml" is because they are reserved for him or something. I do not understand.

Please please help me because no documentation to find and secure here at least we left public for others who want to do something.

Many Thanks and greetings!

Answer (score 0):

First of all - you can't get symfony to intercept all errors. Some of the errors may be server errors and the request won't even get to your application. You can reproduce some of them explicitly setting responses in symfony though, but I may not be necessary to deal with all of them.

As for the exact response: you should use a listener to hook your errors to a class that handles them according to your need. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7077818/580167 for implementation details.

Comment: Hello, you link the article to which I use as much help but I do not understand is, where do I define the "class"? Should I create a new file in "X" route or add it to another file?

The article also says that I have to invoke "$this->dispatcher-> connect...." in "/config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php". I guess it's within the public function "setup", right? Do you also could do it from "/frontend/config/frontendConfiguration.class.php"?

Sorry but I am fairly new to Symfony ... sorry and thanks!